# Payment for Google Cloud Billing Account

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Do I have to have money in my bank account in order to create a billing account in Google Cloud?

Because I have no money to do that.

And Does Google really charge for Google Map Services? If they charge, do you know any other alternative Map Service to use in my mobile app?

Comment: Your question is about a vendor's policy which is off-topic. Google will make a small charge verifying the account has funds and the identity. So yes, you need money on the account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create a billing account there should be some minimal amount through which google will verify your Credit card and this amount will get back to your bank account once your  account is created.

Once you have created a billing account and project you are eligible for the Google Cloud Platform $300 no-charge trial and Google Maps Platform recurring $200 monthly credit. You won't be charged until your usage exceeds $200 in a month. To know more, check  [Billing Account Credits](https://developers.google.com/maps/billing-and-pricing/billing?_gl=1*1rfzpca*_ga*MTA0MzI1ODUuMTY2MTEzOTgxOQ..*_ga_NRWSTWS78N*MTY2MTEzOTgxOS4xLjEuMTY2MTEzOTg3OS4wLjAuMA..#billing-overview)